# How to insert Image into Column Header of CellTable (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

If we use Text for the header then it may take some space, so I want the Header have an icon(like Delete Icon) so I can save some space for the Header.

I tried

```
myCellTable.addColumn(deleteColumn,new SafeHtmlHeader(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant
("<img width=\"30px\" height=\"30px\" src=\"image/icon/delete.png\">")));
```

It showed the image but the Image is very small about (10px - 10px) and it has a ugly border around the image.

SOmeone said using CUstom Header, but I couldn't override `getHeaderStyleNames()`. Ex:

```
class DeleteHeader extends Header{
    @Override
    public String getHeaderStyleNames(){
        return "css style";
    }
}
```

It said i have to override supertype something....!!

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header.setHeaderStyleNames("deleteHeader");
```

Do not render image in this header. You can use a standard TextHeader, for example.

In CSS define this style with image as a background.

Comment: Hi awsome solution, but how to style the Header since the image occupy the whole Header column even i set small size. .columnHeader{
 background:url('/images/icon/delete.png');
 background-size::16px 16px;
}

Comment: it seem ok, but how to centralise the image? text-align:center didn't work. The image was aligned to the left of the header

Comment: i fixed "background-position:center;". Again, thax you very much for your answer. This is the most elegant solution for putting image into header.